# Subscription to route params not triggering

Tags: angular, subscription, routeparams

I am using `ActivatedRoute` and subscribing to its `params` to get triggered. But, the subscription is not triggering.

Code:

```
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params : any) => {
        console.log(params);
    });
}
```

I am unable to know the issue. Please help me solve this.

Thank you...

Comment: what you mean to get data when it get the same? you are trying to do detect when you are rerouting to the same route?

Comment: Route for the first time also not triggering the subscription.

Comment: is the route data is changed ?

Comment: Yes. It is changed.

Comment: Are you using the angular router?  Do you have a <router-outlet> in your HTML somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same in `ngOnInit()` and it works..

You have syntax error i guess..(**subscribe parenthesis)**

```
 this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);

       //call function here for data change
    });
```

Comment: its not the parenthesis

Comment: check in the question if subscribe function parenthesis is closed..??

Comment: it must have been a typo..the editor will throw an error for this missing parenthesis

Comment: it is a typo.. i have checked in editor
subscribe is a function whose parenthesis needs to be closed

Comment: param type will not be any.. please refer my answer

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `queryParams`:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor( private _route: ActivatedRoute ) { }
...
ngOnInit() {
    this._route.queryParams            
        .subscribe(
        params => {                
            console.log(params);           
        });
}
```

Comment: I am not sending `queryParams`. Using `urlParams`.

Comment: You should use queryParams. Check this [example](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/)

Comment: That is my choice and preference to use `routeParams`. Indeed I need to send like that only.

Comment: This should work: `constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activatedRoute
 .params
 .subscribe( 
     params => {
     console.log(params);
 });
}`